# Invalid allocation size: 4294967295 bytes

Tags: c++

I'm trying to build my first C++ app and I'm trying to browse a table. However, the debugger display this error message.

```
DWORD *dwWatch = new DWORD[taille]; // <-- The error appears here.
for (LISTSTR::iterator i = listMe.begin(); i != listMe.end(); ++i, j++)
    {
        dwWatch[j] = m_DirWatcher.WatchDirectory(m_strDirectoryToMonitor, dwChangeFilter, pHandler, true, NULL, NULL);

    }
```

How do I fix this, please ?

Comment: Presumably `taille` is extremely large. How it got that way is impossible for us to know.

Comment: Looks to me like `taille` is -1, which is then taken as a `unsigned` value, and thus turns into a very very large number.

Comment: also don't forget to initialize `j` in your loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real value of taille is -1, because 4294967295 of unsigned int and -1 of signed int are both 0xffffffff in memory.

So check out when did its value change to -1. Note that some standard functions return -1 on fail.

Comment: On 32 bit 2's complement machines anyway; the standard makes no such guarantees.